# How can you set a custom frame size for AV Foundation camera capture?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapture

I am working from the AVCam sample application, which uses AV Foundation for camera capture.

When I use the following preset:

```
[self.captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];
```

I get a 480 x 360 video frame from the camera.

However, I want a frame size of 320 x 192. How can I set a custom preset to obtain frames of this size? If it helps, the iOS version I'm targeting is 4.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to do this is: you set the frame of AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to custom value, such as 320*192. Then you can get the Image that you want.